# How to append an integer to a list in a for loop? to understand list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
some_list = [1,2,3,4]
for x in some_list:
    new_list.append(x * 2)
```

Generates the following error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

I want output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I am asking this to understand list comprehension:

```
new_list = [x*2 for x in some_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an empty list before you can append to it with a `for` loop.

```
some_list = [1,2,3,4]

new_list = []
for x in some_list:
    new_list.append(x * 2)

new_list_2 = [x*2 for x in some_list]
```

After the above, both `new_list` and `new_list_2` contain `[2, 4, 6, 8]`

The `for` loop and the list comprehension are functionally equivalent.

The principal difference that was causing your error is that the `for` loop has the requirement that you must define the list before you can append to it. List comprehensions automatically generate the list object for you.

Comment: If you do `new_list = some_list` after the for loop then yes this is similar to that

Comment: Thanks David. is this the same as: new_list = [x*2 for x in some_list] ? Please clarify